# Does the offline character builder allow you to apply the Lich template to a character or must this be done manually?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-4e-character-builder

I am planning on turning a recurring character in our current campaign into a Lich at an as-yet-undetermined point in the future. I know the DMG provides a template for doing this, but it would be nice to be able to use the Character Builder for this. I am using the last update of the Offline Character Builder.

Comment: There is a fantastic 3rd party adventure called *Brother Ptolemy and the Hidden Temple* that offers PCs access to lich-dom through ritual and feat support. It's well done and *not* over-powered but offers enough to the players to make someone in the right mindset consider the feat tax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the offline character builder never supported monster templates.

Answer (score 5):

**You may be asking the wrong question, the tool for Game Masters is "Adventure Tools."**

From a theoretical perspective, it is impossible to apply "monster" templates to "player characters." The rules governing monsters and PCs are simply different. It is possible to give monsters powers that act *similiar* to what PCs have, and it's certainly possible to call them the same thing, but the fundamental mechanics are different.

Your best choice for a recurring villain is to use *adventure tools* to apply the lich template or to create a custom monster that matches your thematic requirements. While Adventure Tools does not support templates as templates, it's quite trivial to edit in a template's specific requirements.

Comment: I will certainly keep this in mind for other circumstances, but this character is meant to be an NPC, not a monster. He is not explicitly a villain, and may even fight alongside the PCs at times. Ultimately the PCs will decide if he is a villain or ally and I want him to be governed by PC rules until such a time as it is no longer viable from a mechanics perspective.

Comment: Fair enough. Even NPCs use monster mechanics though. See the generation of "Splug" in WotC's Dark Awakenings encounter. Beyond that, he should just take the Lich Epic Destiny to reflect that he is indeed... a lich.

Comment: I ended up on this question looking around to see if there was any way for a PC to become a lich. Mentioning the Epic Destiny helped me out.

Answer (score 4):

There is a 3rd party app, [cbloader](http://code.google.com/p/cbloader/), that can be used to extend and create new offline character builder content.

You may be able to use this to apply a lich template to your character.

Comment: The wiki is extensively documented...

Comment: @Brian indeed it is